# Why solr dismax query returns empty resultset?

Tags: solr, edismax, dismax

I'm trying to get free-text search results from indexed data with solr 4.5 using [Dismax Query Parser](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin) but no results returning and no errors with simple queries like this:

```
http://localhost:9999/solr/products/select?q=cuir&qf=text_fr&defType=dismax
```

And these documents are exists in index:

```
{ id: 1, label: "Sac à main en cuir" }
{ id: 2, label: "Sac à main en cuir rouge" }
```

My schema.xml is:

```
..
<field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" /> 
<field name="label" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
...
<copyField source="label" dest="label_fr"/>
<dynamicField name="*_fr" type="text_fr" indexed="true" stored="false" />
...
<fieldType name="text_fr" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer> 
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_french.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="French"/>
    <filter class="solr.CollationKeyFilterFactory" language="fr" strength="primary" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

and in solrconfig.xml

```
...
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
    <int name="rows">10</int>
    <str name="defType">dismax</str>
  </lst>
 ...
```

So any ideas what is wrong? Why there are no results?

Comment: You can use the analysis tool that comes with Solr and debug. You can access it at `http://HOST:PORT/solr/#/CORE/analysis`

Answer (score 2):

KeywordTokenizer treats your whole index string as a single token, so it won't match to a single word query.

Instead, you may try StandardTokenizerFactory, or WhitespaceTokenizerFactory, or WordDelimiterFilter.

Answer (score 0):

In the above schema you've defined the field "label" as "string" and it is treating it as a single string

You Should change the fieldType to :

`<field name="label" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />`

And as mentioned above the text_general fieldType by default has the StandardTokenizerFactory configured.

It'll treat the field as text (or strings) and you will be able to perform full-text search on it.

Note : FieldType String is good in case of faceted search for a particular category in that case you must use String for better results. or you can do a CopyField.